# Compute rowmeans ignoring na in pandas, like na.rm in R

Tags: pandas

I have the following data:

```
a = pd.Series([1, 2, "NA"])
b = pd.Series(["NA", 2, 3])
df = pd.concat([a, b], axis=1)
#     0   1
# 0   1  NA
# 1   2   2
# 2  NA   3
```

Now I'd like to compute the rowmeans like in R with `na.rm=T`.

```
c.mean(skipna=True, axis=0)
# Series([], dtype: float64)
```

I was expecting:

```
# 0  1 # 1/1
# 1  2 # (2+2)/2
# 2  3 # 3/1
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed `dtypes` due to presence of str 'NA', you need to convert to numeric types first:

```
In [118]:
df.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='force')).mean(axis=1)

Out[118]:
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: float64
```

If your original data was true `NaN` then it works as expected:

```
In [119]:
a = pd.Series([1, 2, np.NaN])
b = pd.Series([np.NaN, 2, 3])
df = pd.concat([a, b], axis=1)
df.mean(skipna=True, axis=1)

Out[119]:
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: float64
```

Comment: FYI: when only passing kwargs to ``.apply``, you can do it directly: ``df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='force').mean(axis=1)``

Comment: @Jeff thanks for the note, I tend to use `lambda`s when the function takes args as a default usage